# Set Ctrl + <arrow-key> as shortcut in nano

Tags: linux, shortcut, nano

In virtually any text area on computers nowadays, if you use the combination ctrl + arrowkeys it will move through text by words(left and right) or paragraphs(up and down), and ctrl + shift + arrowkeys will highlight chunks successively. Even this  stackoverflow textbox has this smartly implemented.

I can't find anyone asking whether such a fix, patch or option enables the same in the terminal text-editor nano. I use nano for a lot of coding and it would be so wonderful to have it there.

Does anyone know of such a patch? Would anyone suggest a replacement? (Dear god, please don't suggest I use the dinosaur that is visudo)

Thanks Gals and Guys!!

**Update:**
"Gedit" was pretty much what I was looking for, although its not a commandline editor and I don't feel as l33t, it works great and has syntax highlighting.

Comment: Why did you tag this as `python`?

Answer (score -3):

Linux and Unix have a multitude of text editors available for them. I would suggest emacs, but if you find that too slow to start up, there are a number of lightweight emacs alternatives available; one such is zile.

Comment: It looks like zile does not have the keyboard shortcuts I'm looking for. Thank you for the suggestion though.